# Share library with web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I want to use a library both in the main thread of a website and in the context of a webworker.
In the index.html I do:

`<script src="https://someCDNUrl"></script>`

Then in the web worker I do

`importScripts('https://someCDNUrl')`

It works but I see two requests to the CDN. Is it possible to request the resource only once?

Comment: this might help. https://addyosmani.com/basket.js/

Comment: You shouldn't worry about this so much. If the CDN's HTTP server is configured properly, your browser will cache the javascript file.